# Granting permissions in Liferay Document library

Tags: java, permissions, document, liferay

I have a simple requirement and I want some advice on implementing this the best way in liferay.

I am using Liferay Document library.
My requirement is to group users into different departments. (A, B and C).

- userA --> dept A
- userB --> dept B
- userC --> dept C
- The userA should have access to only directories belonging to A
- userA can grant files access to 'userB' or all users in 'B'

How should I group the users the best way so that I can grant these permissions.
Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

To give some pointers:

You can [create Organizations](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/managing-users-user-groups-organizations-sites-teams-and-roles) (departments) like Org A, Org B and Org C.

Then you can assign the Users accordingly to the Organizations.

To restrict usage of certain directories or folders, you can create Organization-level-roles and assign them to your Users.

Now you can assign permissions to the created Organization-level-roles for different directories.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any of the groups to inherit permissions from other groups, you could also use "User Groups." This is basically the same as organizations, except they're nonhierarchical and would use regular level permissions instead of Organization level roles.